# How to set the value of $_GET on page start as a value if its null? simple php

Tags: php, forms, input, radio-button

i want the the default value to be set to 5 min minutes meaning the value to be 1 when i start the page.  not sure how to set the value for min before hand.

```
   <input type=radio name="min" value = "1"  <?php if($_GET["min"]==1){ echo "checked";}?>> 5 Min
   <input type=radio name ="min" value = "2"  <?php if($_GET["min"]==2){ echo "checked";} ?>> 20 Minutes
   <input type=radio name = "min" value ="3"  <?php if($_GET["min"]==3){ echo "checked";} ?> > 1 Hour
```

Comment: $_GET["min"] = default value

Comment: nope the page still starts it as null if i set it that way

Comment: $_GET["min"] == '' ? default : $_GET["min"];

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new variable and set it's default value to 5 and then check if you get any value for requested flag then set the updated value to that variable other wise it will take the default value.

Ex.

```
<?php 
    $intMin = 1;

    if($_GET["min"] != NULL){
       $intMin = $_GET["min"];
    }
?>    
<input type=radio name="min" value = "1"  <?php if($intMin == 1){ echo "checked";}?>> 5 Min
<input type=radio name ="min" value = "2"  <?php if($intMin == 2){ echo "checked";} ?>> 20 Minutes
<input type=radio name = "min" value ="3"  <?php if($intMin == 3){ echo "checked";} ?> > 1 Hour
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the problem, you want to check the option 5 min even if $_GET is not defined ? the following code will do the job

```
<input type=radio name="min" value = "1"  <?php if( !isset($_GET['min']) || $_GET["min"]==1)){ echo "checked";}?>> 5 Min
<input type=radio name ="min" value = "2"  <?php if($_GET["min"]==2){ echo "checked";} ?>> 20 Minutes
<input type=radio name = "min" value ="3"  <?php if($_GET["min"]==3){ echo "checked";} ?> > 1 Hour
```

Comment: There was a indent typo sorry

Comment: When you first load the page, there is no $_GET, so it will check the 5 min option

Comment: What's the default value of $_GET ?

Comment: even if i use this im still getting the notice min is undefined, i want to define it

Comment: The OP asked how to "set the default value" not "check if it's not set", which is all you have added. I know this will essentially work, but I don't see why you'd just check if something is *not present* (not set) when the OP actually has a known and required variable *default*. Just set it to the default, then any checks will fall through naturally. I've removed my downvote however, as that was from your previous code formatting issue.